# Is it possible to disable/enable all shortcuts in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to fix my keyboard shortcuts and I'd like to rule out any conflicts that may be happening with my OS shortcuts (the one from settings > keyboard shortcuts), so the idea is to turn them all off temporarily and go to the software that is missing the key hits to fix what needs to be fixed then turn the OS shortcuts back on, like a toggle kind of thing.

I already tried to remap some that may indicate conflicts but I never get it fixed, for example, I have set visual studio code to copy line down to control + alt + shift + down arrow, but this combination specifically does not work and I do not know where the problem comes from. There are a bunch of other shortcuts that worked without problems in Ubuntu 18.04 but since I upgraded to 20 they have stopped working

Comment: What is your current desktop environment?

Comment: Hi @N0rbert, I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean. I have downloaded and Installed Ubuntu 20.04 stock, just as it comes when you download the ISO, no mods or anything. In that case, what would my desktop environment be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer to the question as in the title: yes. However, it is not possible with a single toggle.

System wide keyboard combinations are scattered over a range of keys in the dconf settings. You can see all these settings in `dconf-editor`. Quite a lot, but not all, system wide keyboard bindings are under `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/` and some are under `/org/gnome/mutter/`.

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd>, for example, is used system wide to move a window to another workspace. That is defined as `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down ['<Super><Shift>Page_Down', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']`

Comment: Thank you vanadium (for some reason I cannot tag you)
This is the kind of information I was looking for, too bad there is no way to have a single toggle to do so but I'll have a look at those locations.
I am aware of the default move-to-workspace-down shortcut, those were the first ones I have changed to something else in order to apply the ctrl+alt+shift+down but it still did not work, nothing comes out of this combination, and btw the new combination I have set to move-to-workspace-down worked as intended, so it must not be that specifically.

Comment: So just deleting `, '<Control><Shift><Alt>Down` in dconf-editor to delete that key binding does not work to have the key working in visual studio? I disabled `'<Control><Alt>Down` to enable the "move paragraph" keybinding with success. Perhaps also check the keybindings in Visual Studio whether the key is properly defined there (I do not know it, but I suspect Visual Studio provides extensive  possibilities to customize key bindings)